# Why does this return a None, when there is a post in the database

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

My objective is to display the number of comments/posts that a blog contains. I have written the code to get from a database and will be called by self.comment_num.  However although there is clearly a post in the blog, self.comment_num returns a None.

Python code

```
class Blog(object):
    def __init__(self, author, description, author_id, _id=None, comment_num=None):
        self.author = author
        self.author_id = author_id
        self.description = description
        self._id = uuid.uuid4().hex if _id is None else _id
        self.comment_num = Database.count(collection='posts', query={'blog_id': self._id}) if comment_num is None else comment_num

    def json(self):
        return {
            'author': self.author,
            'author_id': self.author_id,
            'description': self.description,
            'comment_num': self.comment_num,
            '_id': self._id
        }
```

Each `Post` object contains a `blog_id` which is the same as the blog objects id. Hence the `database.count`.

Database.py file

```
class Database(object):
    URI = os.environ.get("MONGOLAB_URI")
    DATABASE = None

    @staticmethod
    def initialize():
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(Database.URI)
        Database.DATABASE = client.get_default_database()

    @staticmethod
    def insert(collection, data):
        Database.DATABASE[collection].insert(data)

    @staticmethod
    def delete_one(collection, query):
        return Database.DATABASE[collection].delete_one(query)

    @staticmethod
    def find(collection, query):
        return Database.DATABASE[collection].find(query)

    @staticmethod
    def find_one(collection, query):
        return Database.DATABASE[collection].find_one(query)

    @staticmethod
    def update(collection, query, data):
        Database.DATABASE[collection].update(query, data, upsert=True)

    @staticmethod
    def count(collection, query):
        Database.DATABASE[collection].count(query)
```

I called the count function and provided a collection and query.

Blog object as shown in database.

```
{
    "_id": "a6d836d23f524f21becbcf85c54dca90",
    "author": "Jongbin1010@gmail.com",
    "author_id": "09e116fa1a4a41aa8ec272f28809860b",
    "description": "Hello",
    "comment_num": null
}
```

Post object. The blog_id of the post object matches the _id of the blog object

```
{
    "_id": "812e2e1725604e899af0c4484d7209e6",
    "blog_id": "a6d836d23f524f21becbcf85c54dca90",
    "author": "Jongbin1010@gmail.com",
    "content": "boy",
    "upvotes": 1,
    "created_date": {
        "$date": "2017-07-31T05:29:33.034Z"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show how do you create instances of Blog class?

Comment: is this line a comment?? if comment_num is None else comment_num

Comment: comment and post is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` doesn't actually return the value, unlike the other methods.

Comment: You mean, there is no **return** keyword in the count method?